# How to compress image in Glide on Android

Tags: android, android-image, android-glide

I want show image in my application and for show images I use Glide library. 
In my codes I can change image size but I want compress images.

```
Glide.with(context)
        .load(model.get(position).getImageUrl2())
        .placeholder(R.drawable.default_image)
        .override(900, 600)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
        .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model,
                                           Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                return false;
            }
        })
        .into(holder.newsImage);
```

How can I compress images?

Please help me

Comment: Please explain **in detail**, what  you mean by "How can I compress images?"

Comment: @CommonsWare, my image size from server is large, I want first set lowly size and when set images, such as if image size is 100kb, compress is to 80kb. this numbers just is sample, I want compress images

Comment: @CommonsWare, can you help me my friend?

Comment: Images are only compressed on disk, as part of storing them in a particular file format (PNG, JPEG). You are not saving images on disk. You are loading them into memory.

Answer (score 0):

Get your image

```
Drawable drawable = getDrawable(R.drawable.bird);
```

Get the bitmap from drawable object

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
```

Initialize a new ByteArrayStream

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
```

Compress the bitmap with JPEG format and quality 50%

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,50,stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
Bitmap compressedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray,0,byteArray.length);
```

Use the compressed Bitmap to load image. 
I know its not what you want but i think it might helps you.